# Store and retrieve private key from Mac keychain programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, keychain, private-key

In a Mac application, I have a requirement to store the private key sent from the server for logged in user in a secure way and retrieve it back whenever needed programmatically. I know that keychain is the best place to store the private key. Is there any sample code available to achieve this?

I am able to add the private key to the keychain using "SecKeychainItemImport" method of "Security.framework" but having issues retrieving back the private key from the keychain. I have tried using "SecKeychainItemCopyAttributesAndData" and "SecKeychainItemCopyContent" methods for getting private key back from the keychain. But no luck so far.

I have also read in blogs mentioning private key storage inside ".ssh" hidden folder. But I feel that storing the private key inside the keychain provides one more level of security so that someone else can not have an easy access to the private key.

Comment: Hello @Subhash, Who's key are you storing? A private key you generated for the user, or your applications private key?

Comment: Private key is generated for a user. Server will generate a private key for the user based on the information provided by the user when he tries to login for the first time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One purpose of the Keychain is to keep private keys protected by not exposing their data to the application. To prevent accidentally exposing a private key, these items are flagged `CSSM_KEYATTR_EXTRACTABLE | CSSM_KEYATTR_SENSITIVE` by default; i.e., it is only possible to get their data using `SecKeychainItemExport`, and only in a passphrase-protected format.

There are APIs in the Security framework that encrypt/decrypt/sign/verify etc. data using a supplied key item without ever putting the raw key data in the application's address space. (These operations are normally done by a separate, privileged process.)

If for some reason you do need access to the private key's raw bits, you need to prepare for this at the time you import the private key to the keychain. You need to set `keyAttributes` to `CSSM_KEYATTR_EXTRACTABLE` (i.e., without the sensitive bit) in the `keyParams` parameter of `SecKeychainItemImport`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Keychain is what you'd use here. You want to read the documentation first, then look at Apple's sample code.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am looking for storing/retrieving a private key in Mac application. The sample code link is related to iPhone. Moreover I am not looking for storing username and password. I am specifically looking for private key management programmatically in Mac.