# Remember data when login in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new in here and I just develop on Mac application. I have log in form and I want to remember data (username, password) for running next time without filling data and click sing in. Please help. Thank in advance.

Comment: i deleted my answer because it's for iPhone not for mac. Please go with @danielbeard answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521156/store-and-retrieve-private-key-from-mac-keychain-programatically

Answer (score 3):

If it is sensitive data like usernames and passwords, you should be using the keychain.

Have a look at the [keychain programming guide for OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html)

[SSKeychain](https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain) is a great Objective-C wrapper that works for both iOS and OSX and simplifies keychain programming.